# Perl Cookie not working

Tags: javascript, perl, cookies

I already spent all day looking for an answer for this:

I am using Perl with LWP::UserAgent and HTTP::Cookies.

My problem is that I can't get past an cookie-base age-check.

In Perl I use this code:

```
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $resp = $browser->get( $url, 'User-Agent' => 'MySpider/1.0' );

#Cookie Setup
my $cookies = HTTP::Cookies->new();
$cookies->set_cookie(1,'age_check', '1','/','.example.com/', 80, ,0,3354512128, 0);
$browser->cookie_jar($cookies);
```

The Site is setting the Cookie with JavaScript

```
function saveSplash(domain) {
    var expDate = new Date();
    expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime()+(1*24*3600*1000));
    setCookie("age_check", 1, expDate, '/', domain);
    setCookie("screen_width", getScreenWidth(), expDate, '/', domain);
}
```

This is the Cookie saved by my browser:

```
age_check
1
example.com/
1088
3354512128
30140182
2646218624
30139981
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems with your `set_cookie` call. First, the domain should be `".example.com"` without a slash; the slash is specified in the path parameter. Second, you're missing a value for the path_spec parameter, so the value you specify for discard (0) is being used for maxage, which results in an expired cookie.

Answer (score 0):

(Update: quite missed the point.)

I hope you didn’t really spend all day looking. :( The first result on Google for [LWP::UserAgent JavaScript](http://www.google.com/search?q=LWP%3a%3aUserAgent+javascript) is [Handling Javascript with LWP::UserAgent](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=559996) which gives the punchline: it doesn’t support JavaScript. There are a couple of options though.

Check [Mechanize JavaScript](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=mechanize+javascript&mode=all) on the CPAN. It leads to [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox) and [WWW::Mechanize::Plugin::JavaScript](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aJavaScript). There is also scripting with [WWW::Selenium](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aSelenium) which is a bit trickier but will perfectly emulate the browser because it really is running the browser.

Upate: forgot about [WWW::Scripter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aScripter) which actually relates to Mech::Plugin::JavaScript.

Comment: The OP is obviously aware that Mech does not support Javascript. That's why he is attempting to set the cookie manually.